# Ionic 2: Disable Scrolling at Page Level

Tags: ionic-framework

How is it possible to disable page scrolling by using setScrollDisabled(disableScroll) per the Ionic 2 documentation. It seems as of RC2 that this is no longer working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aways override the scroll-content style in your `.scss` file.

```
scroll-content {
   overflow-y: auto;
}
```

or you can set `overflow-y: hidden;`

Comment: That is what I am currently doing, but I was hoping to use the ionic framework.